# Unable to locate krb5-admin-server krb5-kdc

Tags: apt, software-installation, 14.10

I am trying to install Kerberos5 on my ubuntu-14.10-server-64bit, then I type the command:

sudo apt-get install krb5-admin-server krb5-kdc

I receive

E: Unable to locate package krb5-admin-server
E: Unable to locate package krb5-kdc

What can be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to do a `sudo apt-get update` to update the repos cache before `apt-get install`?

Comment: Thank you, update really helped me to get the repositories. Everything works fine

Comment: One more question: I have created a KERBEROS.TEST realm and after addprinc root/admin also I added mu client machine as principal, I checked kinit and with sudo klist command I received the ticket on my kerberos server, but unfortunately from my client machine I receive this mess: "Cannot contact any realm 'KERBEROS.TEST' while getting initial credentials"

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @ionchirca hello, if you have another question that is totally different from this one, please feel free to open a new question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this as an answer because it solved the problem.

Do a `sudo apt-get update` to update the repos cache before `sudo apt-get install`